# How can I remove %26 and %3D from url?

Tags: magento2, sorting, price-sorting

When I want to sort products by price (low to high and high to low), my link is not working.  Option value is "price&product_list_dir=asc", which encode in "price%26product_list_dir%3Dasc".
How can I decode that url?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="toolbar-sorter sorter">
<label class="sorter-label" for="sorter"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sort by') ?></label>
<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options selectpicker">
    <?php
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $path = strstr($url, '?');
    ?>
    <option
        <?php if($path == '?product_list_order=price&product_list_dir=desc'): ?>
            selected="selected"
        <?php endif; ?>
        class="high-low" value="price&product_list_dir=desc">
        Price - High to low
    </option>
    <option
        <?php if($path == '?product_list_order=price&product_list_dir=asc'): ?>
            selected="selected"
        <?php endif; ?>
        class="low-high" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('price&product_list_dir=asc') ?>">
        Price - Low to high
    </option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: What is not working? Is the "selected" not echoed properly? Is there extraneous "%26 and %3D" in the value attribute of the html so it says like '<option value="price%26product_list_dir%3Dasc">'? Is the sort order not changing after you select a different type of sort? Please specify what is not working so we can help you more quickly.

Comment: I checked with Inspect Element and option value is echoed properly. When I click on the option, page redirect to mysite.com/category.html?product_list_order=price%26product_list_dir%3Dasc . But when I change "%26" and "%3D" into "&" and "&" directly into Address Bar, it works. It seems that, when I click on the option, Magento encode that option value in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the browser that's encoding the value correctly as expected. Check out https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/ for safe characters.

In my opinion the best way to do it would be just to set the value to something like "price$product_list_dir!asc" or "price+dir-desc" or just "price_desc" and parse the value of product_list_order in your code. Other options are:

- Split the menu to two drop-down menus (product_list_order and product_list_dir)
- Update the url with javascript when the pulldown selection changes

Comment: Thank you. I added onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" to select and <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
 $('select').on('change', function() {
  var url = $(this).val();
  if (url) {
   window.location = url;
  }
  return false;
 });
});  
</script>
Now it's working.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change this `echo __('price&product_list_dir=asc')` to this `echo 'price&product_list_dir=asc'`

Comment: Thank  you for your help but it's not working